# String problems with Turbo C++

Tags: c++, string, turbo-c++

I need to get code work in Turbo C++. But the data type `string` does not work;
using namespace `std` gives Compiler Error and I can't use `string` without it. Even `std::string` does not work.

It works perfectly fine in Code::Blocks but I want it to work in Turbo C++. I know Turbo is a very old compiler and I should be using the new ones. But it is a college project which has to be done in Turbo C++. Are there any ways to make it work in Turbo C++?

Comment: Turbo C++ is *old*, ancient really. Most importantly it is from before C++ was standardized, and so doesn't have the standard headers or the standard namespace. If you need to use Turbo C++ then you need to learn the pre-standard classes and headers. Your best chance is to pick up an old book, from the early to mid 1990's. And then you have to live with the knowledge that much of what you learn won't really be useful in the future, it will be a waste of time.

Comment: i know i have to do this work for some one who wants it done in turbo c++

Comment: @George yeah i did

Comment: The someone that's telling you it _must_ be done in Turbo C++ should be shot.

Comment: Tip: when asking questions, There Is No Need To Capitalise Every Word You Are Saying, it is harder to read. Just use an initial capital and a capital for names (e.g. Turbo C++).

Comment: ok i will keep that in mind

Comment: Your college is ripping you off.  Complain. Besides, most users here probably were in preschool when TC++ fell out of fashion, and so may not be terribly familiar with it.

Comment: not my collage actually my client

Comment: https://turboc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples Please go to their examples and find what you are missing...

Comment: @user49557 You seriously have a client, which is still using software, which is developed with Turbo C++? Well, I guess, if the program works... I *do* hope it is a legacy software dating to 20+ years ago or, because anything newer than that should have been done with something else even originally.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If memory serves, I think namespace std was supported as early on as in BC++ 3.1.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: The C++ of Turbo C era is basically a different language, than what C++ is today. So think of them that way. Sure, they have a lot of similarities, old one is mostly a (small) subset of current one, with a few differences, but modern "recommended" C++ style and best practices and so on are completely, totally different.

Comment: @George in standard C++ it must be `<cstring>`

Comment: @hyde yeah i seriously have a client like that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, after a lot of hassle, I found the way. Unfortunately, you can't use `string` and other such data types as they were not even implemented at that time. You need to do what used to be done before. Use `char` array instead of `string` and create functions related to that.
Now `char` array has a lot of limitations and problems, that's the reason `string` was implemented. But you have to write `char` array functions the same way `string` was written from scratch.
If you want to compare or copy two char arrays, you have to loop and compare them. It will be little complicated, but that's the best way which worked for me.

I can give some sample code for a certain task if needed.

Answer (score 4):

This kind of depends on which version of Turbo C++ you have. Some software archeology:

Ancient DOS versions up to 3.1 didn't support STL well, nor did they support `#include <string>`. They used the pre-standard include formats with .h extensions: `#include <string.h>` etc. Try to add a `.h` and you might get lucky.

Somewhere around version 4 or 5.0 they started to support `#include <string>` header formats and most of STL. These were still pre-standard compilers.

STL support remained questionable in earlier versions of Borland Builder, until somewhere around Builder 5. That should be version 5.5 or so of the BCC compiler.

The RAD tool called Turbo C++, released somewhere around 2005, should have full support for C++98.

Answer (score 2):

Turbo C++ doesn't support namespaces.

I think you need to include `cstring.h` and not use any namespaces or even the `using` directive.

```
#include <cstring.h>
```

And I don't think it supports templates either.

Comment: `cstring` serves for null-terminated strings (aka C-strings), not `std::string`. OP might have to rewrite the whole code to use C-strings instead of `std::string`.

Comment: @Melebius - cstring.h, not cstring.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was string.h. cstring.h will not give you std::string.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no way whatsoever to make modern C++ code work in Turbo C++ as is. Lots of it needs to be rewritten.

There is nothing std:: in turbo c++. There are no namesoaces. There are no templates. There is very little of what we know as the standard library. Basically you have to unlearn most of what you know about C++. Classes and functiins mostly do work. Iostreams may somewhat work if you `#include <iostreams.h>` (note the .h) and omit `std::`. Otherwise you are pretty much confined to the C standard library.

If you need a string class, you probably will have to make your own.

Tread carefully, read the built-in help, examine the included example programs, and you might be able to pull it off.

Note, later versions of the product (not called Turbo C++ IIRC, but rather Borland C++ or Borland Builder) have improved support for C++98, including the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem then I realized that I had forgotten `using namespace std` That solved everything.

Answer (score -1):

In place of String you can use the character array.
For example, we need to declare the variable str as a string. It can be done simply as:

```
char a[10]; // the 10 is the size of the array.
```

A seperate header file    is included to use the library functions.