# Why we need virtual in this program (Turbo C++)?

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I have been coding in Turbo C++ regarding **multiple inheritance** and the aim of the code is to just take the input and print the inputs at the console. I have done the following code initially,

```
// Program to demonstrate multiple inheritance

#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>>
#include <string.h>

class Company1
{
protected:
  int productID;
  char *productName;
  char *CompanyName;

public:
  void input_c1()
  {
    cout << "Provide Company 1 Details : " << endl;
    cout << setw(29) << setfill('-') << "" << endl;
    cout << "Enter the Product ID : ";
    cin >> productID;
    cout << "Enter the Product Name : ";
    gets(productName);
    cout << "Enter the Company Name : ";
    gets(CompanyName);
  }
};

class Company2
{
protected:
  int productID;
  char *productName;
  char *CompanyName;

public:
  void input_c2()
  {
    cout << endl << "Provide Company 2 Details : " << endl;
    cout << setw(29) << setfill('-') << "" << endl;
    cout << "Enter the Product ID : ";
    cin >> productID;
    cout << "Enter the Product Name : ";
    gets(productName);
    cout << "Enter the Company Name : ";
    gets(CompanyName);
  }
};

class SuperMarket : public Company2, public Company1
{
public:
  void Company_details()
  {
    cout << endl << "Company 1 details : " << endl;
    cout << setw(20) << setfill('-') << "" << endl;
    cout << "Product ID   : " << Company1::productID << endl;
    cout << "Product Name : ";
    print_string(Company1::productName);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Company Name : ";
    print_string(Company1::CompanyName);
    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "Company 2 details : " << endl;
    cout << setw(20) << setfill('-') << "" << endl;
    cout << "Product ID   : " << Company2::productID << endl;
    cout << "Product Name : ";
    print_string(Company2::productName);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Company Name : ";
    print_string(Company2::CompanyName);
  }
  void print_string(char *ptr)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i != strlen(ptr); i++)
      cout << ptr[i];
  }
};

void main()
{
  char choice;
  clrscr();
  SuperMarket s;
  s.input_c1();
  s.input_c2();
  s.Company_details();
  cout << endl << "Do you want to exit ? (Y/N) : ";
  cin >> choice;
  if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y')
    exit(0);
  getch();
}
```

and got the output as following when executed,

[image: Click here to see the output]

But that wasn't the output which is expected because the **Company Name** of **Company1** is **dklm** instead it was expected to be **def**. I further on tried to rectify it and made the derivation type of **Company1** as **virtual public** and this resulted in correct output. I heard that **virtual** is used mostly in the cases of **Diamond problem**. Despite not being a **Diamond problem** it has resulted in the correct output. Can anyone please explain why did I get such kind of wrong output in the mentioned program and how did the virtual made to work the program properly in this case ?

Comment: Obligatory reminder that Turbo C++ is horribly outdated, consider using a compiler from this millenium.

Comment: Turbo C++ isn't dead.. yet? You learn something new every day.

Comment: *"I heard that virtual is used mostly in the cases of Diamond problem."* Not really: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class

Comment: It's amazing that so many can dig up an almost 30 year old compiler, but can't seem to download g++ or even Visual Studio 2019 Community, which are free and modern.

Comment: "I have been coding in Turbo C++" - Then I advice you to *stop right now* and get a modern compiler that actually supports standard C++ and has not been outdated for ~30 years and that people actually *use*. GCC, clang and Visual Studio are all available for free and are up-to-date with modern language versions.

Comment: @N.Wouda Of course not! you only need [3 of these](https://i.blogs.es/3cb8ee/4376127476_9770b873d1_o/1366_2000.jpg)

Comment: A lot of this Turbo C++ usage is due to some parts of the world (seemingly South Asia) still using this compiler as part of the curriculum, which is highly unfortunate.  It's like taking a TV repair course, and learning about how to replace vacuum tubes.  However I have seen persons who, when given the choice, *still* choose to use Turbo C++ -- for those persons, there is absolutely no excuse.

Comment: Your code has **undefined behavior because** it uses uninitialized pointers that points to random memory inside your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pointers `productName` and `CompanyName` are uninitialized, so you can't use them as if they point to valid storage for some characters. You should just use `std::string` instead of `char*` pointers, to save yourself from this and a lot of other issues.

Though Turbo C++ doesn't have `std::string`, but maybe you can find a good string class for it if you must use that compiler. I can't really help much more with that, since Turbo C++ hardly even counts as C++ at this point.

Comment: Not probably; [definitely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40399628/485343).